# java regex: negation of a match

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, negation

Although I read a large number of posts on the topic (in particular using lookarounds), I haven't understood if this more general case can be solved using regular expressions.

setup:
1) an **input regex** is passed in 
2) the input regex is embedded in a **negative regex** so that  
3) anything that is **not identified by the input regex** is matched

Example:

given:

```
input regex: "[-//s]";
```

and

```
text: "self-service restaurant"
```

I want a negative regex wherein to embed my input regex so that I can match my text as:

```
"self", "service", "restaurant"
```

Importantly, the negative regex should also be able to match a simple string like:

```
"restaurant"
```

Note, what I want to do could be achieved changing the input regex from

```
"[-//s]"
```

to

```
"[^-//s]"
```

Yet, I'm after a more general approach where any regular expression can be passed into a negative regex.

Comment: try `[^-\\s]+`. Use the same for all.

Comment: It looks like you want to `split` your string on passed regex (you may just want to surround passed regex with `(?:userRegex)+` to avoid empty results like `"fo--o".split("-")` where result would be `["fo", "", "o"]`).

Comment: `String myRegex ＝ "[^" + "yourRegexHere"` might do the trick, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: In general there is no such thing as a "negative regex". The only regex you can negate is a character class. Even writing a negative for something simple like `ab` is rather complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this through matching or splitting.

1. Through matching.

   ```
   String s = "self-service restaurant";
   Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^-\\s]+").matcher(s);
   while(m.find()) {
       System.out.println(m.group());
   }
   ```

You need to put the pattern inside a negated character class to match all the chars except the one present inside the negated class.

2. Through splitting.

   ```
   String s = "self-service restaurant";
   String parts[] = s.split("[-\\s]+");
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
   ```

This would split your input according to one or more space or hyphen chars. Later you could join them to get your desired output.

3. Through replacing.

   ```
   String s = "self-service restaurant";
   System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[-\\s]+", "\\\n"));
   ```